# Why is [NSNull null] value not added to NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating an NSDictionary using the code below, and I am expecting to have the key @"originalMessageId" contain an [NSNull null] when originalMessageId.intValue == -1.

But my Logger writeToLogFile method gives the following output:

```
2014-04-07 19:16:52: JSON Params: {
    addressId = 1;
}
```

I've stripped the code down to where it is only trying to add the two keys, and still it's not adding the originalMessageId key.

Where am I going wrong?

P.S. The code fails when I load the app as a distribution build, but seems to work when I load the app as a development build.

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict;

SourcePhoneNumber *sourcePhoneNumber = [DatabaseInterface fetchDefaultSourceNumber];

[Logger writeToLogFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sourcePhoneNumber = %@", sourcePhoneNumber]];

if (originalMessageId.intValue == -1)
{
    //NSString *uuidString = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];

    jsonDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:1], @"addressId", /* should be sourcePhoneNumber.addressId */
                //messageBody, @"messageBody",
                //contacts, @"contacts",
                //uuidString, @"clientId",
                [NSNull null], @"originalMessageId",
                nil];
}
else
{
    jsonDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:1], @"addressId", /* should be sourcePhoneNumber.addressId */
                originalMessageId, @"originalMessageId",
                messageBody, @"messageBody",
                contacts, @"contacts",
                nil];
}

[Logger writeToLogFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"JSON Params: %@", jsonDict]];
```

Comment: Why are you using the archaic method of setting up a dictionary, instead of the (much nicer) inlined version?

Comment: Do you know for sure that `originalMessageId.intValue` is equal to `-1`? if it's not `-1` and `originalMessageId` is `nil`, you will get the output you are seeing.

Comment: @rmaddy that doesn't seem correct, if originalMessageID is nil you'd get an exception. " If any key is nil, an NSInvalidArgumentException is raised."
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-CBHCIFDD

Comment: @RobP No, that is not correct with the `NSDictionary initWithObjectsAndKeys:` method. That method simply iterates through the variable list of arguments and stops when it encounters a `nil`. That `nil` can be the explicit `nil` added at the end or in a case like this, if one of the variables happens to be `nil`. Your statement is correct with something like the `NSMutableDictionary setObject:forKey:` method.

Comment: ah I see, the exception is if a *key* is null, not a value. My bad. Upvoted your answer as the likely explanation. It seems so many of these questions could be resolved in seconds if people would learn to use the debugger and step through, inspecting values...

Comment: @RobP Actually `setObject:forKey:` will cause an exception if either key or value is `nil`. But `initWithObjectsAndKeys:` will simply stop adding keys and values as soon as it hits a `nil` argument.

Comment: @RobP And yes, you are correct that this question (and similar) are easily solved using the debugger. It's far more efficient than adding a bunch of log statements and posting questions here.

Comment: @rmaddy is there a document somewhere here on SO with "XCode debugging basics"? If not can I write one and what's the best way to make it easily findable? I've seen 100 posts in the last few weeks where I'd have linked to it if I know one existed...

Comment: @RobP I'd check the Xcode docs from Apple.

Comment: Well of course I use that doc a lot, but a one page summary of basics  for the beginners with a few screenshots here would sure help a lot. I think I'll try to find a way to contribute one for XCode and one for Android Studio.

Comment: Richard J. Ross III - I am using this method of setting up a dictionary because it's the one I am the most comfortable using.

Comment: maddy -
I had myself (very wrongly) convinced that the problem only happened when I was loading a distribution build.  I do not know of a way to use the debugger in that case.  If there is a way, I'm all ears!  I was somewhat blinded by considerable stress I'm under trying to meet a deadline, and I apologize for the somewhat silly question.

But thanks to great information from you and David, my eyes were opened and my bug is exterminated! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output you are seeing will happen if `originalMessageId` is `nil`. This will cause your `if` condition to fail going to the `else` part. And if `` `originalMessageId `` is `nil`, that `nil` terminates the creation of the dictionary at that point leaving only the `addressId` key and its value.

So you need to determine why `originalMessageId` is `nil`.

Comment: I don't want to rush to downvote in case I am mistaken, but see my comment above. I am pretty sure a nil argument in the middle you get an exception, not a shorter dictionary.

Comment: @RobP See my comment to yours above.

Comment: @RobP as rmaddy said, initWithObjectsAndKeys: iterates through value /key pairs until it encounters a nil value.  It will only throw an exception if the value is non-nil and the key is nil.  If originalMessageId is nil, then originalMessageId.intValue = 0, you hit the else clause, and get the results you're seeing.

Comment: I got trapped in my own assumptions about what was happening, and of course, originalMessageId was nil.  Thanks for your helpful comments, and your patience with my apparent stupidity. :-)